# Knockoutjs kendoPanelBar not working when looping through a list

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-panelbar

Does anyone know what's happening with my code wherein I can't seem to get kendoPanelBar working with a code like this:

```
<ul data-bind="kendoPanelBar:{}">
  <!--ko foreach: Students -->
  <li>James
     <ul>
       <li data-bind="text: Age">Age: 25</li>
       <li data-bind="text: Score">Score: 9/10</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

but, if not inside the foreach loop the panelbar is working fine.

```
<ul data-bind="kendoPanelBar:{}">
  <li>James
     <ul>
       <li>Age: 25</li>
       <li>Score: 9/10</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hopefully you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@super cool sorry for late response

By the way thanks for your effort. Anyway I was able to make it work by doing like this:

```
  <div data-bind="with: $root.Room">
  <ul data-bind="kendoPanelBar:{}">
  <!--ko foreach: Students -->
   <li>James
      <ul>
        <li data-bind="text: Age">Age: 25</li>
        <li data-bind="text: Score">Score: 9/10</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <!-- /ko -->
 </ul>
 </div>
```

wherein $root.Room is a field in my MainVM

Answer (score 2):

you are not properly closing the `container-less` foreach at the end .

**view:**

```
<ul data-bind="kendoPanelBar:{}">
  <!--ko foreach: Students -->
  <li>James
     <ul>
       <li data-bind="text: Age">Age: 25</li>
       <li data-bind="text: Score">Score: 9/10</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <!--/ko--> /*correction here*/
</ul>
```

*Straight from* **Docs :**

> The `<!-- ko --> and <!-- /ko -->` comments act as start/end markers,
>   defining a “virtual element” that contains the markup inside. Knockout
>   understands this virtual element syntax and binds as if you had a real
>   container element.

Comment: Already edited. Sorry, that was just a typo error. The problem was not that one.

Comment: are you getting data at students ? share us your viewModel or possible a fiddle with code @confused .

Comment: I'm getting the data of students because the loop is working, but the panelbar is not.